# Preserving IDs when using gCentroid to find centroids of multiple polygons in R

Tags: r, polygon, raster, r-sp, centroid

This seems like it should be simple. I have multiple polygons contained in one shapefile, and I am using the `gCentroid()` function from rgeos to create a bunch of centroid points. The function has an `id` argument which should return the parent geometry Ids if left unspecified, but this is either not working or I'm looking in the wrong spot or I misunderstood the argument.

Simple example:

```
library(terra)
library(rgeos)
library(sp)

v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
v <- as(v, "Spatial")

#Clearly there are IDs here (albeit not unique) 
v@data[["ID_1"]]
```

so when I go on to create centroids

```
cents <- gCentroid(v, byid = TRUE)
```

I don't see any associated "ID_1" slot. The issue is I will eventually be using these centroids to derive values from a raster, and will need the IDs to distinguish which polygon the values originate from.

Comment: You might want to take a look at `st_centroid` in the `sf` package. Using this function will conserve the original attributes in the parent geometry.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be

```
library(terra)
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
x <- centroids(v)
```

of with `sf`

```
library(sf)
y <- st_centroid(st_as_sf(v))
```

With rgeos you would need to do something along these lines

```
library(rgeos)
s <- as(v, "Spatial")
cents <- gCentroid(s, byid = TRUE)
atts <- data.frame(v)[as.integer(row.names(cents)), ]
s < SpatialPointsDataFrame(cents, atts)
```